# Make another window on button click?

Tags: java, forms, popup, window

I want to know in a code example, how do I get a new window with a unique type of form to pop up when I click on a button?  I now this is simple, but my code is not doing what I need it to do.

Comment: please show us the code that you already have and what exactly its not doing.

Comment: What does "a unique type of form" mean?

Comment: *"I want to know in a code example"*  I want world peace.  Looks like neither of us get what we want.  (SO is not a code generation machine.)  BTW - when people will inevitably ask [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), they will expect better answers than *"my code is not doing what I need it to do"*.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best attempt.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  When I say unique it has to look different then what one of the other forms look like.  When I click the add customer button, a window pops up that asks for name, address, city, state, zip, and phone#.  I want to make another window called "Find Customer" that pops up a window that just has the fields for name (first and last) and allows the user to search for a particular customer.

Comment: if I post my code ... will that help???

Comment: Seriously you are either joking or have never actually written UI code before! If you can write a form that allows you to enter name, address, city, state, zip and phone# with a button to submit you have figured out how to write a form and bind to a click event. Hence you don't need us to spoon feed you all the code for your assignment. And yes post code but all that is needed is a SSCCE showing the click handler and 2 windows you are working with. Emphasise where the find button click event is handled.

Comment: The question is tagged "java" and "forms" but some people can point you to a awt/swing/gwt solution. Do you mean windows-forms or to do that in a web-page (meaning javascript more than java in that case)

Comment: @travels: your comment was mean and not helpful. Thank you for your contribution. You too at one time had to be helped. Please consider being kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dimension D=this.getSize();
Point p=this.getLocation();
fs.setSize(D);
fs.setLocation(p);
this.dispose();
fs.setVisible(true)
```

Here fs is the object of the frame which u have to display (subclass of javax.swing.JFrame )
And write this code as an event of button